# Can entire Sentence be searched with text type in elastic search 7

Tags: elasticsearch

Does Text mapped Field only look for words in a sentence in elastic search.

Let's say I am searching for **my name is aditya**,
So if we have mapped the field as keyword then only exact match will work, that's correct,

but let's say I am searching for **my name is aditya** with field as text so if individual tokens are searched the results will appear, as text fields are analyzed and suppose we use standard in-build analyzer which produces lowercase tokens.

Will they also appear if entire sentence is searched

Comment: It will appear if you do phrase search - "my name is aditya". All lowercase so no issue

Comment: so that means this is possible either with match query or keyword mapped field but not with text. Am I right ?